# CodeBuild <> GitHub - Hooks broken

Tags: github, continuous-integration, webhooks, aws-codebuild

I'm using AWS COdeBuild with GitHub on several projects, and I noticed today that it doesn't work anymore. Something's broken, and I don't know what.

[image]

I have configured CB to automatically build when a PR is updated. It used to work fine, but now it shows "Expected", without any link toward the CodeBuild build. And, on CodeBuild interface, there isn't any build running.

It's as if the commit on the PR didn't trigger any build on CodeBuild.

Considering everything was working fine, and I don't believe I've made any change to the GitHub nor CodeBuild configuration. **So, what could be the reason for the build not to be triggered? What should I look for?**

> Manually triggering a build from CodeBuild UI works fine, and is properly sync with the PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was both stupid and simple: I had renamed the GitHub repository using a different case.

I.e: 'myproject' > 'MyProject'

Changing the source in CodeBuild to load the new source (with updated case) fixed it:
`https://github.com/UnlyEd/MyProject.git`

Simple, stupid, and so easy to miss. GitHub handles very nicely those name changes and there is no need to change the local git config, as it treats older names as aliases. But CodeBuild must somehow check for the source repository name and doesn't handle case changes.